# Real-time notification upon registration using SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, notifications, asp.net-boilerplate, asp.net-core-signalr

I want to send real-time notification in ASP.NET Boilerplate. Notification is saving successfully in **Abp.NotificationSubscription** table on subscription. When I publish the notification, the notification got saved in the **Abp.Notification** table but it is not displayed to the user in real-time.

My server-side code:

```
public async Task<RegisterOutput> Register(RegisterInput input)
{
    public async Task<RegisterOutput> Register(RegisterInput input)
    {
      var user = await _userRegistrationManager.RegisterAsync(
          input.Name,
          input.Surname,
          input.EmailAddress,
          input.UserName,
          input.Password,
          true
      );

      _notificationSubscriptionManager.SubscribeToAllAvailableNotifications(user.ToUserIdentifier());
      await _appNotifier.WelcomeToTheApplicationAsync(user);

      var notification = _userNotificationManager.GetUserNotifications(user.ToUserIdentifier());
      await _realTimeNotifier.SendNotificationsAsync(notification.ToArray());

      // ...
    }
}
```

`_appNotifier` implements `WelcomeToTheApplicationAsync(user)`:

```
public async Task WelcomeToTheApplicationAsync(User user)
{
    await _notificationPublisher.PublishAsync(
        AppNotificationName.WelcomeToTheApplication,
        new SendNotificationData("Naeem", "Hello I have sended this notification to you"),
        severity: NotificationSeverity.Success,
        userIds: new[] { user.ToUserIdentifier() }
    );
}
```

`SendNotificationData` inherits from `NotificationData`:

```
public class SendNotificationData : NotificationData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }

    public SendNotificationData(string _name, string _message)
    {
        name = _name;
        message = _message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171078/discussion-between-muhammad-naeem-akhtar-and-aaron).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to sent welcome notification to the user when he registers itself by using the register link on the login page. In the **CloudbaseLine.Application** project ... we have **AccountAppService** which contain the code for registering the user and sending notification to it after successful registration but the problem is notification go saved in **Abp.NotificationSubscriptionTable** and **UserNotificationTable** but user cannot received them.
>
> ```cs
> public async Task<RegisterOutput> Register(RegisterInput input)
> {
>     var user = await _userRegistrationManager.RegisterAsync(
>         input.Name,
>         input.Surname,
>         input.EmailAddress,
>         input.UserName,
>         input.Password,
>         true
>     );
>
>     _notificationSubscriptionManager.SubscribeToAllAvailableNotifications(user.ToUserIdentifier());
>     await _appNotifier.WelcomeToTheApplicationAsync(user);
>
>     var notification = _userNotificationManager.GetUserNotifications(user.ToUserIdentifier());
>     await _realTimeNotifier.SendNotificationsAsync(notification.ToArray());
>
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> ```cs
> public async Task WelcomeToTheApplicationAsync(User user)
> {
>     await _notificationPublisher.PublishAsync(
>         AppNotificationName.WelcomeToTheApplication,
>         new SendNotificationData("Naeem", "Hello I have sended this notification to you"),
>         severity: NotificationSeverity.Success,
>         userIds: new[] { user.ToUserIdentifier() }
>     );
> }
> ```

The user is not connected to the SignalR hub in the `Register` method.

One way to handle that is to [enqueue a background job](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Background-Jobs-And-Workers#add-a-new-job-to-the-queue):

```cs
await _backgroundJobManager.EnqueueAsync<WelcomeNotificationJob, UserIdentifier>(
    user.ToUserIdentifier(),
    delay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
);
```

```cs
public class WelcomeNotificationJob : BackgroundJob<UserIdentifier>, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly IRealTimeNotifier _realTimeNotifier;
    private readonly IUserNotificationManager _userNotificationManager;

    public WelcomeNotificationJob(
        IRealTimeNotifier realTimeNotifier,
        IUserNotificationManager userNotificationManager)
    {
        _realTimeNotifier = realTimeNotifier;
        _userNotificationManager = userNotificationManager;
    }

    [UnitOfWork]
    public override void Execute(UserIdentifier args)
    {
        var notifications = _userNotificationManager.GetUserNotifications(args);
        AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => _realTimeNotifier.SendNotificationsAsync(notifications.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Don't forget to [register data formatters](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Notification-System#client-side) for custom notification data types, on the client side:

```js
abp.notifications.messageFormatters['CloudBaseLine.Notification.SendNotificationData'] = function (userNotification) {
    return userNotification.notification.data.message;
}
```

Comment: Its working fine. Thumbs Up man. You saved my day. Thank you very Much.